# Perform a task at a specific time in Rails without using cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to delete some records from the database each day at midnight.
Is it possible to do this without using a cron job or various gems like whatever and delayed_job?

The record is a just a counter, it counts each time a user clicks on a certain button but only allows 10 clicks per day, once 10 is hit the button is disabled. The users count is reset to 0 at midnight.
Could the count be stored in a session variable and set to expire?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you really couldn't use cron, you could run ruby script on your server:

```
while true do
  sleep 3600

  if Time.now.hour == 0
    `bundle exec rake run:your:thing`
  end
end
```

But cron is ideal for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to delete the record? You could just save the date when updating the counter, and reset the counter when the last saved date does not equal today.